# How to detect laser line position on an mm graduated ruler

Tags: opencv, aforge

Hi I am trying to identify the best method to capture the laser mark on a mm graduated ruler located a few feet away from the laser / optical camera (static state - not moving). I wonder if I should: 1)  use an object (maybe the ruler) as a "pixel size" reference to derive the length from the "zero" ruler edge to the laser mark or 2) use ocr or 3) blob recognition (mm lines) and counting these lines between zero and the laser mark to interpret where the laser is aiming e.g. the 85mm line on the attached image.  Does anyone can shed some light as to what would be more precise or easier? Any help on figuring this out is appreciated.  [drawing example of laser line on ruler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZfXSL.jpg)

Comment: What have you tried so far? What is the actual problem you're trying to solve? Any other constraints or requirements? Do you have some sample images? In short - please elaborate :) | If the scene is static (only the laser spot moves), then you don't really need to detect the ruler at all -- after removing distortion, calibrate it with the spot at several known locations and then interpolate the position. Picking out the spot ought to be simple with correct exposure, just threshold and find the centroid.

Comment: Thanks Dan. This is an alignment tool I am trying to build. It will be placed 8-9 feet from a target inside or out (some sort of mm graduated 1 meter ruler). The 2 constraints I have are: 1) shoot for 1-2mm accuracy 2) the target may not be 100% square with the cam,  it may be a 1-2 degree off.  I could use the ruler as a reference object to do pixel to length conversion but I wondered if I could use some form of blob/ocr recognition to return the actual laser line - ie I can see with my eye that it is aiming at the 128mm mark - can I train the detection engine to see it as well?

Comment: I would cut off the ruler just a bit longer than the widest item I wanted to measure and then detect its ends which is easier than OCRing the digits. And, with a nice, long reference length, your accuracy will be higher.

Answer (score 0):

Al tough your question is very general I'll recommend a possible solution using some assumptions:

- your camera is fixed, so is the ruler/reference area you're using
- your ruler is mainly horizontally aligned (a few degrees won't hurt much, use triangulation to get the math)
- the laser pointer is strong enough to have a bright and contrasted representation on your cam's image
- the laser beam is almost vertical. If so, it's not important to measure exactly at the rulers markers (they actually disturb more than they can help)

I'd definitely discourage any use of OCR here- even if some or all above assumptions are wrong. It's hard to get it working anyways and most probably if not an overkill a simple killer for your project.

With the assumptions above I'd try the following:

Preparation:

- First: calibrate zero by the number of pixels (from left to right) where the ruler's zero line is. As long as the ruler isn't moved this needs to be done only once, the number can even be hard-coded.
- Then: calibrate some known distance, e.g. use the last visible digit on the ruler, count the pixels and divide by that digit. Now you know the number of pixels per digit. The more pixels per digit you have the better measures you can later make.

Measuring:

- extract only one horizontal line of the image - best option would be the center where we have no disturbing content - just the laser beam and the reference area
- drop/remove/ignore all pixels up to the zero- calibrated pixel
- find the pixel with the highest brightens value. If you can identify the line but with some width take the mean value (the middle of the line).
- count the pixels form zero to this highest value and divide by pixels per digit.
- **DONE**